# Pandas charts claims a DataFrame is not a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, bokeh

I need to draw a dead simple bar chart with count summary of some case categories. The exception message puzzles me. Most likely I've made some mistake here but still, the error message seems absurd!

```
import bokeh.io
import bokeh.charts
bokeh.io.output_notebook()

plotdata = pd.DataFrame([{'category': 'a', 'cases': 2}, {'category': 'b', 'cases': 4}])
p = bokeh.charts.Bar(plotdata, values='cases', label='category')
bokeh.charts.show(p)
```

Exception:

```
ValueError: expected a dict or pandas.DataFrame, got    cases category
0      2        a
1      4        b
```

I'm using Python 3 BTW.

Comment: p should be some bokeh type? use plotdata?

Comment: It works for me: python 3.5, bokey 0.11.1, pandas 0.18.1.

Comment: Works for me too: bokeh 0.12.0, pandas 0.18.1, IPython 5.1.0, Jupyter 4.2.1, Python 3.5.2

Comment: Does not work in mine. BokehJS 0.12.5, Ipython 4.1.2, Jupyter 4.3.0, Python 3.4.3.